# Is there anyone knows how facebook mobile app talk to the server?

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, networking

Recently I am doing a research on the request/response model of the facebook mobile app. I am using the fiddler 4 to capture all the http/https conversation from the facebook app on my iphone 4s. What I did was setting my desktop as a proxy and redirecting all the iphone network  traffic through it. By the way, I have configured the fiddler so that all the https conversations are also transparent.

One interesting thing I find is that, although I am able to capture all the requests and responses for the graphics and jsons. I never found any request regarding the Comments or Likes, nor can I find any information of the new feed that's in plain text.

My question is, did I miss something or such "plain text" conversations are happening on a different transport layer or with some different protocol?

How am I able to get these conversations in my fiddler?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

All communication with the server API should be running over HTTPS. It means it's SSL encrypted and you are unable to see the plain text communication on your proxy. That behaviour is on purpose to protect the users data. You surely wouldn't be happy if anybody on a way of packets from your iPhone to the Facebook API's could read your messages for example :-)

You are saying you made "https transparent". I don't know what exactly you mean, but unless you make classical man-in-the-middle attack by faking certificates, you have no chance to see the open text communication of HTTPS. And I think FB has it covered and will detect change of certificates.

Edit: I just have checked it out using Charles proxy and yes, all the communication to the Facebook API is (of course as expected) HTTPS, so you will never see any open text communication.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, you guess right. I have install the custom certificate and perform the man-in-the-middle "attack". That's how I am able to see the traffic like image. But no where can I find the traffic of those plain text. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

As you know, you can easily configure Fiddler to decrypt HTTPS traffic.

My first guess is that the "Like" and "Comment" data are transferred over a HTML5 WebSocket. Do you see any WebSockets in the traffic from the application?

Comment: Nope, actually nothing happened. There is no traffic at all, which is really weird. On the other hand, I could see all the https traffic from an Android device while performing exactly the same activities.